# How to tell the pH of HC2H3O2?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, ph

> Find the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a $\pu{0.500 M}$ solution of $\ce{KC2H3O2}$.

I am preparing for an exam on equilibrium and I have two questions:

1. How would I go about calculating this?
2. Is the $\ce{H3O}$ in the middle of $\ce{KC2H3O2}$ one hydroxide ion?

Here is what I have attempted to do: find the conjugate acid/bases, write out a balanced equation, then take the $-\log{[\ce{H+}]}$ of the conjugate acid. But I am a little stuck on the best course of action to find the conjugate acid/base.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added more info and context to the question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all let us introduce the given compound in a more bonding descriptive way: $\ce{H3C-COOK}$. This compound is commonly referred to as [potassium acetate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_acetate):

[image: structure of potassium acetate]

It reacts with water in the following fashion:
$$\ce{H3C-COOK_{(aq)} + H2O <=> H3C-COOH_{(aq)} + K+_{(aq)} + {}^{-}OH_{(aq)}}$$

Then the [mass action law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action) can be applied in the following way:
$$K_c=\frac{\ce{[H3C-COOH]}\ce{[K+]}\ce{[{}^{-}OH]}}{\ce{[H3C-COOK]}\ce{[H2O]}}$$

And you can then rearrange to form the [base dissociation constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant#Bases_and_basicity):
$$K_b=\frac{\ce{[H3C-COOH]}\ce{[{}^{-}OH]}}{\ce{[H3C-COOK]}}$$

The $\mathrm{p}K_b$ for potassium should be around $4.7$.

As dissenter pointed out, you do not need the [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson-Hasselbalch_equation) to  calculate $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}$ values for a pure solution of potassium acetate. You can have 
a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_base#A_typical_pH_problem) for an example calculation.

---

For your second question:

- [Hydroxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxide) Ion: $\ce{{}^{-}OH}$ or $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{HO-}$ ...
- [Hydronium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium) Ion: $\ce{H3+O}$ or $\ce{H3O+}$ or $\ce{H+OH2}$ ...

Comment: I like how you wrote out all the different ways of expressing hydroxide ion or hydronium ion (some more correct than others). However, I do not see why the OP needs to use the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation to solve this problem. There is essentially no conjugate acid/base pair in this system.

Comment: @Dissenter You are right, for this problem you don't need it - fixed that. However, there is a conjugate acid-base pair in this system. (Incomplete dissolution - you have all species in the first equation)

Answer (score 2):

You need the $K_\mathrm{a}$ value of the solute of interest. That would be $\ce{[C2H3O2]-}$ as $\ce{K+}$ has highly limited Brønsted-Lowry acid/base properties in water.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. Please consider elaborating a little more. Also I disagree on the acid-base properties. It is one of the most commonly used buffer systems.

Comment: Potassium as a buffer? Please elaborate. You are right however I should have probably expanded on my answer but when I posted it appeared that the OP had not given much thought to the question so I merely wished to nudge the OP in the right direction.

Comment: Potassium acetate has the same buffer applicability as sodium acetate just add some acid and your done.

Comment: Right, I meant potassium by itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Are you talking about elemental potassium, then I agree not much of  acid base properties - strung reducing agent though. But the question was about something entirely different: the weak base potassium acetate. (I also corrected your charges.)

Comment: As I wrote in my post, potassium ion has almost no acid/base properties in water.